# How to change the innerHTML of the char js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a Hangman game so I can learn JavaScript, I don't know how to change the innerHTML
of the char I made in js. So when I know if the string includes the guess then i want to make the line which represents the correct guess to transform into a charater and make it apear but when i run the code it turns the last of the lines into the correct guess and makes it disapear when there's a new guess and transforms  the line into  second correct guess. And doesn't reconizez 'o'(the last character that is in the string)
I would like to apologize if I made grammer mistakes.

```js
//defineing the word
var a = 'hello';
// makes the lines 
for ( var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        var letter = document.createElement("h3");
        letter.className = 'letter'+i;
        var j = 2*i+23;
        letter.style ="position: absolute;"+"top: 14%;"+"left: "+j+"%;";
        letter.innerHTML = "_";
        document.body.appendChild(letter);
    }  

//submit btn gets the input and if it's correct shows it, if it isn't correct than puts into a wrong words
function submt(a,letter){
    var inpt = document.getElementById('input');
    if (a.includes(inpt.value)){
        letter.innerHTML = a[a.indexOf(inpt.value)]; 
    }else {
        console.log('wrong')
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hangman</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <p class='letter'>Write the letter in here:</p>
    <p class='bad'> the wrong letters:</p>
    <p class='word'>the word:</p>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="input">
     <button class="sub" id='submit' onclick="submt(a,letter)">submit</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were resetting the letter variable to the last h3 element. You needed a array for each of the slots.

```js
//defineing the word
    var a = 'hello';
    // makes the lines
    var letters = []; // this array store the h3 elements
    for ( var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            var letter = document.createElement("h3");
            letter.className = 'letter'+i;
            var j = 2*i+23;
            letter.style ="position: absolute;"+"top: 14%;"+"left: "+j+"%;";
            letter.innerHTML = "_";
            document.body.appendChild(letter);
            letters.push(letter); // add element to array
        }  

    //submit btn gets the input and if it's correct shows it, if it isn't correct than puts into a wrong words
    function submt(a,letter){
        var inpt = document.getElementById('input');
        if (a.includes(inpt.value)){
            var l = 0, result = [];
            while (l<a.split('').length) {
              if (a.split('')[l] == inpt.value) { // a split('') turns the word into an array so it is easier to search
                result.push(l); // this store the position of the correct letter in the word
              }
              l++;
            }
            var l = 0;
            while (l<result.length) {
              letters[result[l]].innerHTML = a.split('')[result[l]]; // change the h3 elements content to the correct letter using the result array.
              l++;
            }
        }else {
            console.log('wrong')
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hangman</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class='letter'>Write the letter in here:</p>
        <p class='bad'> the wrong letters:</p>
        <p class='word'>the word:</p>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="input">
         <button class="sub" id='submit' onclick="submt(a,letter)">submit</button>
        <script src="script.js"></script>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey @cs641311 could you  explain me your code it  works  really fine but I don't understand how it  works.

Comment: 1.) I added an array called letters that stores each of the h3 elements that represent a letter. 2.)Every time a user guesses a correct letter it checks the word for all instances of the letter in case the word has multiple of the same letter. 3.) Replace the h3 elements that correspond with the letters found

Comment: I will add comments to the code to bettter explain

Answer (score 3):

You are currently accessing always the last dash created.
Thats because createElement will create a h3 element for each char in the word.

```
for ( var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        var letter = document.createElement("h3");
        ...
}
```

After the loop the variable `var letter` will contain the last h3 element created. You defined letter inside a for loop but access it inside a method.
It works in javascript but is a bit unexpected to see.

I assume you are not yet familiar with scopes. That is okay for now but maybe also something you want to read about for future progress.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

---

A solution close to your solution, but which uses an array to save all h3 elements.
Note that I also removed the parameters of `submt()` because you did not use them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hangman</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <p class='letter'>Write the letter in here:</p>
    <p class='bad'> the wrong letters:</p>
    <p class='word'>the word:</p>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="input">
     <button class="sub" id='submit' onclick="submt()">submit</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
//defineing the word
var a = 'hello';
// makes the lines 
var letters = []
for ( var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        var letter = document.createElement("h3");
        letter.className = 'letter'+i;
        var j = 2*i+23;
        letter.style ="position: absolute;"+"top: 14%;"+"left: "+j+"%;";
        letter.innerHTML = "_";
        document.body.appendChild(letter);
        letters.push(letter)
    }  

function submt(){
    var inpt = document.getElementById('input');
    if (a.includes(inpt.value)){
        var index = a.indexOf(inpt.value)
        letters[index].innerHTML = a[index]; 
    }else {
        console.log('wrong')
    }
}
```

Comment: @tamastesnadi. You are welcome. Please consider accepting one of the available answers.